# SWF Full-Width Responsive

Tags: css, flash

I'm trying to embed a SWF File in Full-Width. And when you resize the window, the swf should resize proportionally. I don't know why but I didnt get it working...

This is my last try:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height;">
    
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

   
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="ePaper.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">

        
</body>
</html>
```

The ePaper just display in mini format...

Hope you cant help me...

Thanks.

Comment: width and height 100% react to the size of the direct parent of the element. In your css, have you tried 'html, body { width:100%;height:100% }' as well?

Comment: Isn't working as well.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want to create a container for your SWF. Set the container's width to 100% and set the padding-top to another percent to keep the aspect ratio. For the SWF element itself, set both the width and height to 100%.

```
<style ='text/css'>
.swf{
  width:100%;
  padding-top:59%;
  position:relative;
}

.swf object{
  position:absolute;
  toP:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
</style>

<div class='swf'>
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="mySWF" width="100%" height="100%">
            <param name="movie" value="http://tubeline.ca/fsh/tubeline_sileageHowAndWhy.swf" />
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://tubeline.ca/fsh/tubeline_sileageHowAndWhy.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
            </object>
        </object>
</div>
```

[Working sample here](http://karljuhlke.com/samples/swf.html).